# How can we apply Accounting in Openxml

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

1. 0 should be show like this - Underscore.
2. Minus number should come in Parentheses.
   suppose we have -1 then it should  display (1).
3. if we want to avoid symbol None.

We try below code.

CellFormat cf = new CellFormat() { FontId = fontId, NumberFormatId = 44//"#,##0.00
, ApplyFont = true, ApplyNumberFormat = BooleanValue.FromBoolean(true) };

Thanks in Advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpD5x.png)

Comment: NumberingFormat nformat4Decimal = new NumberingFormat
                        {
                            NumberFormatId =1,
                            FormatCode = StringValue.FromString("#,##0.00_);(#,##0.00)"),
                        };

Comment: FormatCode = StringValue.FromString("_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(*  - ??_);_(@_)"),